# group by while selecting many more columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, grouping

I have this query :

```
select first_name, last_name, MAX(date)
from person p inner join
address a on 
a.person_id = p.id
group by first_name, last_name
```

with person(sid, last_name, first_name), address(data, cp, sid, city)

My question is how I can have a query that select first_name, last_name, MAX(date), city, cp 
without adding city and cp to the group

I mean I want to have all 5 columns but only for the datas grouped by first_name, last_name and date

Many Thanks

Comment: And which city and cp should you choose?. Since you are grouping by the other columns, you either add those to the `GROUP BY` or perform an aggregation function on them: `select first_name, last_name, MAX(date), MAX(city), MAX(cp)`

Comment: Or, you need some method of picking which one you'd like; an order.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Say you have three John Smith in your database, each of them having one or two addresses. When you group by name now, then what city do you want to get? The city of which John Smith and of which of his addresses? As there is no implicit answer to this question, there is no way to write a select statement without explicitly saying which city is to be selected.